# Cordova App ID (iOS Bundle ID) section can't start with number - mine HAS to

Tags: ios, html, cordova, intel-xdk

How do you get around the cordova constraint of the App ID (equivalent to the iOS provisioning profile and xcode Bundle ID) limitation of every section beginning with a letter?

This unique ID is usually a reverse domain style. We have an existing app in the Apple store whose bundle ID has a number starting a section. It is of the form uk.co.12xxxxxxx.xxx To add a new version with a Cordova built app it must be signed with that bundle ID but cordova does not allow it. Can I hack it somehow?

I've used Intel XDK as a gui to cordova but I'm thinking of recreating the build within cordova itself. I don't want to go back to square one and do a native app when we've got a cross platform one working fine (it just needs to be signed with the appropriate bundle ID provisioning file and release to the iOS store).

Answer (score 0):

Answer: You can't.

This has nothing to do with cordova, when you pack cordova into a native app the native app falls under the standards of the platform (ios, android...etc) and there you cannot have numbers as starting point.

For a test you could try to make an empty android project and try to set the package name to "123.example.com" -> you will get "a123.example.com"

Comment: Thanks. The target platform is iOS and the existing native code app has a number starting a section in its Bundle ID. It is not a constraint of the platform I believe. The Bundle ID can't be changed on iTunesconnect either as it has already had previous builds. It appears (from Intel's XDK forums) to be a limitation imposed by cordova. I can give the Android version of this cross-platform app a different name but the iOS one must have a number so that existing users will get their app updated.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get around it by doing a Cordova Package export (on the Intel XDK v3900 build tab) and modifying the `<widget>` tag to include an `ios-CFBundleIdentifier` attribute that specifies the unique App ID for your iOS build. Some sources claim that this attribute has not been implemented in standard Cordova, but I do find it referenced in the [ios-cordova framework repo](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ios-CFBundleIdentifier&type=); perhaps only in one of the more recent versions of Cordova CLI. If that `<widget>` attribute is supported, you'll have to build your app with PhoneGap Build or with Cordova CLI using the exported build package as a starting point, since the `<widget>` tag is not modifiable in the Intel XDK build system.

[This post](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5929#issuecomment-255664090) indicates there is a way to change the ID **AFTER** the iOS package has been built, but you will need access to a Mac (likewise, if you want to build with Cordova CLI directly for iOS).

See [this doc page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/build-xdk-app-with-phonegap-cordova-cli) for more details regarding the export function in v3900 of the Intel XDK.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll investigate.